# Function starts before another finished

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

``My problem is my elaniekle function starts before storagew function ends.So mydownloadurl seems null in database how can I solve that? Thanks.

```
enter code here     ekle.setOnClickListener {
            storage2()
            elaniekle()
    }


        fun storage2() {
        var uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
        var ref = storage.reference
        var imagename = "$uuid.jpg"
        var imagesReference = ref.child("images").child(imagename)
        imagesReference.putFile(imagelist[0]).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
            var deyisen =** FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imagename)
            deyisen.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
               mydownloadurl =  uri
            }
        }
    }
    fun elaniekle(){
            var sikmap= hashMapOf<String,Any>()
            sikmap.put("Email",auth.currentUser!!.email.toString())
            uniqueid = db.collection("Posts").document().id
            sikmap.put("uniqueid",uniqueid.toString())
            sikmap.put("qapaqsekli",mydownloadurl.toString())
            db.collection("Posts").add(sikmap)
    }
```

Comment: post your code where you are calling this two functions

Comment: putFile is asynchronous and returns immediately before the upload is complete.  The listener you attach to the Task it returns is invoked some time later after the upload is complete.  Your code continues executing until that happens, so you shouldn't depend on its results beforehand.

Comment: can you explain which parts of my code I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the callback to complete:

```
ekle.setOnClickListener {
    storage2()
}


    fun storage2() {
    var uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    var ref = storage.reference
    var imagename = "$uuid.jpg"
    var imagesReference = ref.child("images").child(imagename)
    imagesReference.putFile(imagelist[0]).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
        var deyisen =** FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imagename)
        deyisen.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
           mydownloadurl =  uri
           elaniekle()
        }
    }
}

fun elaniekle(){
        var sikmap= hashMapOf<String,Any>()
        sikmap.put("Email",auth.currentUser!!.email.toString())
        uniqueid = db.collection("Posts").document().id
        sikmap.put("uniqueid",uniqueid.toString())
        sikmap.put("qapaqsekli",mydownloadurl.toString())
        db.collection("Posts").add(sikmap)
}
```